# Lease Agreement Error

Tags: lease

When I received my lease it stated $800 per month for a term rent of $10,800. I knew this was a mistake because it was stated in the beginning that rent was $900 per moth. When I corrected the property manager she sent the lease back for $800 per month and $900 per term. I signed and she signed the new document. My resident portal now says I owe $900. Can I hold her to the $800 per month?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I hold her to the $800 per month?

This is somewhat unpredictable from a purely legal standpoint. I assume that *term* means year, since that is what would lead to the rate discrepancies.

The discrepancy of rates *$800 per month* versus *$10,800 in one installment* triggers the [doctrine of *contra proferentem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contra_proferentem), thereby favoring your position that the rent agreed upon is $800 per month.

Additionally, it is noteworthy that despite/upon your notification the property manager sent a "corrected" version preserving the rate of $800/month. That affords to you the argument that the manager/landlord *bore the risk of mistake* in the sense of [*Restatement (Second) of Contracts*](https://www.fbcoverup.com/docs/library/1981-Restatement-Second-of-Contracts-1981.pdf) at § 154.

On the other hand, the landlord is not necessarily barred from "reformation" of the lease even though the mistake clearly was her fault. See *Restatement* at § 157, and the principle of "*avoid[ing] injustice*" (*Restatement* at § 158(2)). From this standpoint, the matter would boil down to ascertaining the parties' intent at the time of formation of contract, and your ability to prove that the $800/month constituted a material inducement to you to enter the lease. That being said, a clause akin to "*[t]his agreement supersedes and overrides any prior or contemporary agreement*" would weaken the landlord's position.

By way of comparison, if you were sticking to the option of "*$900 per term*" as offered in the "corrected" version of the lease, the landlord's chances to prevail would be significantly higher. That is because an argument of *unconscionable exchange* is likelier to outweigh the doctrine of *contra proferentem* regarding the discrepancy in the "corrected" lease.